# Default path to install Nexus Docker Container from AWS EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, dockerfile, amazon-elb, amazon-ecs

Where can I find the default path for Sonatype Nexus (Example: /nexus), MongoDB, Postgres, Jenkins etc. in order to install Docker containers from AWS ECS using Application Load Balancer? I need to create a new Target Group and add the path inside Health Check Settings Path so I can load balance all the applications such as Sonatype Nexus, Jenkins, Centos, Postgres, MongoDB etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking, docker containers with web applications are deployed by convention on "/", and joining the webapp is more a question of `port` than `path`.

You can find information about port on official docker hub or store website ([nexus](https://hub.docker.com/r/sonatype/nexus/), [jenkins](https://hub.docker.com/_/jenkins/), etc...)

```
          |  Path  |  Port  | Docker run example
Nexus 3   |   /    |  8081  | docker run -p8081:8081 --name nexus sonatype/nexus3
Jenkins   |   /    |  8080  | docker run -p8080:8080 --name jenkins jenkins
```

For your databases, same idea, you don't have a "path" to specify to connect to them. You just need to map `ports` and either `publish` them, `link` containers, or use docker `network`.

For instance for [postgres](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres/):

```
docker run --name some-postgres -p5432:5432 -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=mysecretpassword -d postgres
```

Then join the database with something like :

```
//host:5432/db
```

Your AWS ELB would balance the trafic for **webapps** using Target Group (HTTP / HTTPS), but I don't think you can do that for database (TCP only).
I guess **databases** would use `Classic Load Balancer`.

Comment: Hi Francois, Thank you so much for your response. I thought I could use Application Load Balancer (ALB) instead of just Classic Load Balancer in order to load balance applications such as mongodb, postgres, nexus, jenkins etc. What is the difference between Application Load Balancer and Classic Load Balancer? If I have multiple applications that take more loads than just one website, what is the purpose of using load balancer with ECS Container service then?

Comment: Found this [interesting article about ALB vs. CLB](https://www.sumologic.com/aws/elb/aws-elastic-load-balancers-classic-vs-application). I'm not sure everything in your stack *should be* load balanced. Databases *can be* load balanced but they are typically on private network (fast) and designed to provide response effectively... Morevover this needs work on master-master / master-slave replication. Webapps are more often the bottleneck as they may have thousand of opened connections. My advice, you should load test your stack before setting load balancers with ECS.

Comment: Thank you so much again for the response with the clarification. I thought I could or should load balance each applications through ECS container service. The article helps me understand the purpose of ELB and ALB.